# How to avoid page break after \end{multicols*}?

Tags: page-breaking, lyx, multicol

I am experimenting in LyX to create a page which has a single column and two column text.
I inserted the following TeX code in the file.

```
\begin{multicols*}{2}  
        \lipsum[1]  
        \columnbreak  
        \lipsum[2]  
\end{multicols*}  
\lipsum[3]
```

The problem I am facing is Lipsum 3rd paragraph is being created in a new page. How can I avoid this? I want all the three paragraphs in the same page(Paragraph 1 and 2 as two column and Paragraph 3 as a single column below the two column text)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: May I ask why you used initially the starred enviroment?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris , I really don't remember now. I was learning the abcd... of TeX that time and was experimenting a lot. :-)

Comment: @jithinrj eXperimenting... that's the key -- thanks :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `multicols` in place of `multicols*`